# Are plant identification questions ok?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have some photos of a weed that I'm having trouble identifying.  Is that a valid question?

Answer (score 15):

If they're going to crop up and continue to weed about, we should at least edit the titles to be less than generic.

Here's a question title that's too vague and doesn't help external traffic:

> What is this weed?

In fact, it probably doesn't help internal traffic when doing a search or browsing the site.

A great title gives you a heads up to what's ahead. Asking a vague question like the above gives none of that courtesy.

A better version could be something like:

> Identifying a weed that has stocky roots, thorny stems and blue leaves

Comment: The plant puns, they are endless.

Comment: I love this distinction.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, plant (weed) identification questions are a natural part of gardening. In the case you cited, proper identification of the weed is the only way to know how to properly treat for it.

Answer (score 8):

It does raise the problem of duplicates though; having lots of "what is this plant?" questions without any way for that to be especially useful as a long-term resource, with the same plants being asked about repeatedly. It's a limitation of the Stack Exchange software that it's almost impossible to search for a question by trying to find similar images.

In general, Stack Exchange sites are trying to build a searchable knowledge-base of expert information; these questions feel like they'd not be very easy to search though and won't add much value to the knowledge-base.

Plant identification feels like a very niché thing though. Maybe we don't mind as long as it's under a specific tag? I almost want to see a big library of thumbnails of differnt plant pictures so I could search them for one that looks like the plant I'm seeing.

Comment: I agree, and that's why I asked here first.  I've posted the actual question at http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/142/what-is-the-name-of-this-weed with as much searchable metadata as possible.  Hopefully someone could search for "red hairy stems and white flowers" and find my question.

Comment: @lukecyca - Your question is a good prototype for this sort of question. I have similar questions to post. One suggestion: some of keywords/metadata in the **title** will make it easier to scan when searching.

Comment: Would a glossary of common weeds (by country, region or climate zones) help at all? This may be out of scope for an SE site...

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would post [a generic "how do you identify stuff?" question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-do-you-identify-a-plant) to head off these sorts of questions (and because I genuinely want to know). Gaming is full of "identify this game" questions and I'm pretty doubtful about their value to the site. Not to say I'm against "identify this plant", I just think we should keep them to a minimum if at all possible by referring people to general resources (if any exist). Plant identification seems like it *should* be easier than game identification.

Comment: And SciFi has a lot of "identify this book I read 20+ years ago."